# How to rid toxic all purpose cleaner?

Tags: cleaning, safety, chemicals

I recently used an all purpose cleaner that I found out was a highly toxic un-vetted product, according to the EWG. I used it on a couple of shelves. I obviously threw the product away, but how do I know rid my shelves of this toxic, is simply washing it enough? Link to product. http://www.ewg.org/guides/cleaners/1545-SimpleGreenConcentratedAllPurposeCleaner

Answer (score 4):

I did some reading on this. Wikipedia says the following which I checked elsewhere:

2-Butoxyethanol usually decomposes in the presence of air within a few days by reacting with oxygen radicals.[12] It has not been identified as a major environmental contaminant, nor is it known to bio-accumulate.[13] 2-Butoxyethanol biodegrades in soils and water, with a half life of 1–4 weeks in aquatic environments.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Butoxyethanol

The product "Simple Green" is considered to have low toxicity, which means there isn't much to worry about. Only with extreme concentration is there a concern.

From what I read, allow the shelf to air out over a few days if you have concerns.

Comment: If *you* consider this highly toxic (though as mentioned by @dmcdivitt, it is not), then why did you write, "I obviously threw the product away,", when it should have been disposed in a safe manner, e.g. municipal HM collectoin? See http://www.epa.gov/osw/conserve/materials/hhw.htm .

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to clean the shelves again with homemade non-toxic and eco-friendly cleaner. There are tones of recipes on Pinterest. Most of the time I mix some liquid dishwashing detergent and warm water. Or you can call and ask your local [cleaning company](http://www.cleaningcarpet-london.co.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

2-butoxyethanol evaporates pretty quickly once you wipe up the excess. If your shelves feel dry, they are dry and there's no more there to worry about.